# Using a Variable to Dim a Worksheet

Tags: vba, variables, excel

I have a sheet with one cell that is = the name of a folder that I want to dim as a variable. what I want to do is set that cell = the filename variable.  It will probably be easier to look at my code. I am currently getting the "object required error on my "set Input 1" and my way to set the variable is presumably wrong as well

```
Dim WbkA As Workbook
Dim Input1 as string

Set Input1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="G:\Reporting\ReportCompare.xls").worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A4").Value
Set wbkA = Workbooks.Open(FileName:"Input1")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You try to assign a reference of an *object* with the keyword `Set` to a *data type* (**String**).

Remove the keyword `Set` and it's gonna be okay.

Comment: First and foremost thank you; that got me past the variable part but now the Set wbkA = Workbooks.Open(filename:="test") is giving me an error. I feel like I should be putting something other than "test" in the spot where it is but have no idea what. Any thoughts?

Comment: The method _Workbooks.Open_ waits a **FileName** as argument (more detail here : [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx) ) If you use a variable like above, use `Workbooks.Open Input1`

Answer (score 1):

The code needs to be reordered slightly in order to breakout the steps.

- Get the file path and name from the workbook and store it as a string
  variable (Input1).
- Open the file using the value stored in the string variable (Input1).
- Set a reference to the open file as an object variable (WbkA).

Listed below is the code

```
Sub test()

Dim Input1 As String
Dim WbkA As Workbook

  Input1 = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A4").Value 'Get the path and file name
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=Input1  'Open the file
  Set WbkA = ActiveWorkbook 'Set the reference to the workbook

  MsgBox WbkA.Name 'Show the name value from the object.

End Sub
```

Comment: +1. You can just do `Set wbkA = Workbooks.Open Filename:=Input1` though :)